# Getting error when opening word document using Word Interop C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

[image]

This keeps comming up when I'm downloading my word document, but when I reopen it, it works without problems.

This is my code:

```
                object missing = Missing.Value;
            object start1 = 0;

            var wordApp = new ApplicationClass();

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document myDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing,
                                                                                 ref missing, ref missing);

            object doNotSaveChanges = WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
            //object fileStream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Upload/") + fileName,
            //                                                  FileMode.Create);

            object fs = Server.MapPath("~/Upload/") + fileName;

            Range rng = myDoc.Range(ref start1, ref missing);

            try
            {
                myDoc.Application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(ref fs, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                                        ref missing, ref missing,
                                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                                        ref missing, ref missing);

                wordApp.Visible = true;



    //All document information code here
    }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                myDoc.Save();

                myDoc.Close(ref doNotSaveChanges, ref missing, ref missing);
            }

            // The file name used to save the file to the client's system..

            string filename = fs.ToString();
            System.IO.Stream stream = null;
            try
            {
            // Open the file into a stream. 
                stream = new FileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read,
                                        System.IO.FileShare.Read);
            // Total bytes to read: 
                long bytesToRead = stream.Length;
                Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
            // Read the bytes from the stream in small portions. 
                while (bytesToRead > 0)
                {
            // Make sure the client is still connected. 
                    if (Response.IsClientConnected)
                    {
           // Read the data into the buffer and write into the 
            // output stream. 
                        byte[] buffer = new Byte[10000];
                        int length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);
                        Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                        Response.Flush();
            // We have already read some bytes.. need to read 
            // only the remaining. 
                        bytesToRead = bytesToRead - length;
                    }
                    else
                    {
            // Get out of the loop, if user is not connected anymore.. 
                        bytesToRead = -1;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            // An error occurred.. 
            }
            finally
            {
                if (stream != null)
                {
                    stream.Close();
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: You are working in a server / client environment. Where do you get these erros? At the server of client? If you go to the upload folder on the server, do these Word-documents open normally. If you compare these Word-documents with the documents at the client, what are the differences? Do they differ in length? Do they differ in content?

Comment: @MartinMulder, I can open the documents in the upload folder without any problem, and I don't see anything that differs them. All i get is "file is corrupt" when i click on download button..

Comment: If you click on the download button and save the file somewhere, is there any difference about that file? Such as file length? If you do a binary filecompare, what are the differences?

Comment: When I change my `object fs = Server.MapPath("~/Upload/") + fileName;` to `@"C:\" + fileName;` and try to download, then it comes the same error but it says `document_name(1).doc`. Don't know where the (1) comes from, it's the only file there

Answer (score 0):

For repairing a corrupted word file, you should try third party software RecoveryFix for Word recovery tool. This tool will help you in restoring your word file.